# Unknowingly skipping a step in lfs

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, linux-from-scratch

I am working on lfs. And now I have entered chroot and I have completed section 7.6 of lfs version 10.1. But the problem is that I have skipped  building sed in 6.14. And I cant do the step in section 7.7 because sed is used there.
I have tried to get back and build and install sed with user lfs. But I only was able to build and i couldnt install it because of permission problem.
What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you *should* be able to just do a simple `sed` build while inside `chroot` and as your `root` user, like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --bindir=/bin
make
make install
```

Again, ***make sure you're in `chroot`!***